# Python string quotes trouble

Tags: linux, python-2.7

I want to run `ps -ef | awk '$8=="linuxdcpp" {print $2}'` in a python script using os library.

When I try to put this in os.system(). I run into following trouble:

`os.system("ps -ef | awk '$8=="linuxdcpp" {print $2}'")` will raise an error, and similarly `os.system('ps -ef | awk '$8=="linuxdcpp" {print $2}'')`.

How can I resolve this error?

Comment: you can use triple commas, or escape the " with \

Comment: Ah! `'` is a single quote, and `"` is a double quote. I didn't know what you meant but I do now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's quite simple:

```
os.system("""ps -ef | awk '$8=="linuxdcpp" {print $2}'""")
```

> String literals can span multiple lines. One way is using
>   triple-quotes: """...""" or '''...'''. End of lines are automatically
>   included in the string, but it’s possible to prevent this by adding a
>   \ at the end of the line.

Introduction to `Python` [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings).

Comment: aren't three inverted commas meant for comment

Comment: No, you can use anywhere in your code , one of my favorites of python utils

Comment: @udhy It means a multi-line string. People who use them as "comments" are really just creating string values and throwing them away.

Comment: @Two-BitAlchemist I get it.